# Как убрать сайт из поисковой выдачи с помощью ublock origin?

Tags: html, firefox, chrome-extension, ads, google-search

Собственно вопрос: как убрать сайт из поисковой выдачи с помощью правил в ublock origin? Больше всего раздражает qaru.site. Почему-то он всегда в топе выдачи google по техническим вопросам.

Comment: Странно, что вы пытаетесь игнорировать этот сайт. Полезный же он. Там всегда ответы поясняющие...

Comment: @Ученик все ответы там - машинный перевод англоязычного stackoverflow.

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8364

Comment: @andreymal, это совсем не то. Не буду же я добавлять вручную к каждому поисковому запросу список сайтов, которые мне не нужны

Comment: @StariyDed не добавляйте конечно, а другие описанные там варианты чем не угодили?

Comment: Это всё же не совсем то чего я хотел.

Comment: Вариант с изменением поисковой строки в настройках браузера не работает, если искать не через поисковую строку, а через google.com. А это происходит довольно часто, если первый запрос оказался недостаточно точным.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл способ. В Ublock Origin - Настройки - Мои фильтры  добавить строку:
google.*##.g:has(a[href*="qaru.site"])

Answer (score 0):

Для `Google Chrome` есть [uBlacklist](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublacklist/pncfbmialoiaghdehhbnbhkkgmjanfhe)